# Anyone can help me on this simple circuit on Circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I need some help to do this simple circuit on Circuitikz. It's for an electronics report. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You may need to add some of the + - as separate nodes, especially if you want to change the color.  You can use \textcolor{color}{text} in the labels.

Comment: @JohnKormylo or using advanced voltages, see https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#b7

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can really obtain the colors with plain commands, although it is a bit convoluted (that's not in the normal things `circuitikz` does); obviously the use of [advanced voltages](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#b7) can simplify things.

The alignment of the V_ds is easy, but the v_gs one is a bit "let's try to see what happens".

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{voltage=raised}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) node[left]{$V_{\mathit{GS}}$} to[short, *-] ++(0.5,0)
        node[nmos, anchor=G](Q){};
    \draw (Q.D) to[R, l={\textcolor{red}{$R_D$}}, -*,
        v>={\textcolor{red}{$V_{\mathit{RD}}$}},
        voltage/american font=\small\color{red}, 
        name=rd] ++(0,2)
        node[above]{$V_{\mathit{DS}}$};
    \draw (Q.S) to[R, l_={\textcolor{blue}{$R_S$}},
        v^=\textcolor{blue}{$V_{\mathit{RS}}$},
        voltage/american font=\small\color{blue}] ++(0,-2) node[tlground]{};
    \draw ([shift={(-0.2,-0.2)}]Q.G) to[open, v=$V_{\mathit{gs}}$] ([shift={(-0.2,-0.2)}]Q.S);
    \draw (rd-Vto|-Q.D) to[open, v=$V_{\mathit{ds}}$] (rd-Vto|-Q.S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]